# Having J1 and F1 at the same time

Tags: j-visa

I will be interning in the USA this summer and I will be an exchange student again in the USA after the summer (example dates: internship June-end of August 2019; semester starts on September 2019). So, I will need to apply for both J1 and F1 before I travel to US for the first time. Is this possible? I am nervous that if I apply for the second one after getting the first, they might cancel the first. So, is it also possible to state that they should not cancel the previous one?

Thanks.

(Note: My country is listed for the 2 year home residency requirement, but I think it would not be effective in this situtation because I will not be chaning status inside US and both visas are nonimmigrant).